# VueJS Handlebars Property or method s not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js

I'm using Nodejs with `handlebars` as view engine. I also use `vuejs` in `hbs` files. Now I came to a problem with a function. So I iterate users and then I try to pass the username to the function and when I execute the function I get this error:

`Property or method "Thomas" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render`

This is the code:

```
<button @click="serveUser({{username}})" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Add</button>


methods: {
    serveUser(username) {
        console.log(this.username)
    }
}
```

It won't be logical to define every username in `data` in vue. How can I fix this ?

**UPDATE MORE CODE**

```
{{#each notServedUsers}}
<li>
    <p class="badge badge-danger">NEAPTARNAUTAS</p>
    <span class="username">{{username}}</span> #{{ticketID}} 
    <button @click="serveUser(username)" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Aptarnauti</button>
</li>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `username` as a variable in your event handler if it is a vue property:

```
<li v-for="{username,ticketID} in notServedUsers">
    <p class="badge badge-danger">NEAPTARNAUTAS</p>
    <span class="username">{{username}}</span> #{{ticketID}} 
    <button @click="serveUser(username)" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Aptarnauti</button>
</li>
```

Comment: I get blank space

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your method, you're using this.username when you should use username since you're passing the variable to serveUser like this:

```
<button @click="serveUser(username)" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Add</button>


methods: {
  serveUser(username) {
     console.log(username)
  }
}
```

Here you have a working JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SilliconMachine/zv5L1hs8/14/